# How does Flink treat timestamps within iterative loops?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How are timestamps treated within an iterative DataStream loop within Flink?

For example, here is an example of a simple iterative loop within Flink where the feedback loop is of a different type to the input stream:

```
DataStream<MyInput> inputStream = env.addSource(new MyInputSourceFunction());
IterativeStream.ConnectedIterativeStreams<MyInput, MyFeedback> iterativeStream = inputStream.iterate().withFeedbackType(MyFeedback.class);
// define an output tag so we can emit feedback objects via a side output
final OutputTag<MyFeedback> outputTag = new OutputTag<MyFeedback>("feedback-output"){};
// now do some processing
SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyOutput> combinedStreams = iterativeStream.process(new CoProcessFunction<MyInput, MyFeedback, MyOutput>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement1(MyInput value, Context ctx, Collector<MyOutput> out) throws Exception {
        // do some processing of the stream of MyInput values
        // emit MyOutput values downstream by calling out.collect()
        out.collect(someInstanceOfMyOutput);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(MyFeedback value, Context ctx, Collector<MyOutput> out) throws Exception {
        // do some more processing on the feedback classes
        // emit feedback items
        ctx.output(outputTag, someInstanceOfMyFeedback);
    }
});

iterativeStream.closeWith(combinedStreams.getSideOutput(outputTag));
```

My questions revolve around how does Flink use timestamps within a feedback loop:

- Within the `ConnectedIterativeStreams`, how does Flink treat ordering of the input objects across the streams of regular inputs and feedback objects? If I emit an object into the feedback loop, when will it be seen by the head of the loop with respect to the regular stream of input objects?
- How does the behaviour change when using event time processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, Flink doesn't provide any guarantees on the ordering of input objects. I've run into this when trying to use iterations for a clustering algorithm in Flink, where the centroid updates don't get processed in a timely manner. The only solution I found was to essentially create a single (unioned) stream of the incoming events and the centroid updates, versus using a co-stream.

FYI there's [this proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66853132) to address some of the short-comings of iterations.